# EF6: Forcing Navigation Property to load after setting FK Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm finally upgrading from EF 4.5 to EF 6.1 but I'm encountering some different behaviors I'm not able to overcome.  I'm working with a Database-First design.

I have a Person table with a CompanyID FK property and a Company navigation property:

```
public partial class Person
{
    ... other properties ...
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

When I load a person object using the syntax

```
dbcontext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)
```

the returned person object has the CompanyID set and the Company property is lazy loaded as expected (I use the Database.Log to output generated SQL and verified Company is lazy loaded).

My problem is when the CompanyID is initially null.  If I set it's value, I cannot get the Company property to lazy load based on the new CompanyID value.  This worked in EF4.5, so I was hoping there was a similar way in EF6 to get the same behavior.

Any ideas?  Thanks in Advance.

*** Edited *** I forgot to include the "virtual" keyword on the Company property in the code example above.

Comment: Are you sure your class is lazy loaded at all? I don't see any `virtual` keyword there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I hooked up the DBContext.Database.Log method to output to the console so I can see the generated SQL and database calls.  calling the dbcontext.Persons.FirstOrDefault method results in a select statement against the Person table only, then accessing the Company property generates a select statemetn to the Company table.   So as long as the CompanyID property is initially set, the Company property is lazy loaded.

Comment: How about `dbcontext.Persons.Include(p => p.Company).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)` ?

Comment: Presumably you have called `SaveChanges()` after setting the CompanyID and prior to referencing the Company property?

Comment: I have not, and was hoping there was a way to not have to call SaveChanges() first.  I didn't before in EF4.5, so do I have to now in EF6 to get the navigation properties to update themselves after the FK field is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are right, there seem to be some weird lazy loading behaviors in EF6.

For the rest of the readers, here are the two scenarios that show two (both incorrect) behaviors. Assume the database contains 2 `Company` records with `Id` = 1 and 2, and `Customer` record with `CompanyId` = 1.

(A)

```
var e = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
e.CompanyId = 2;
var c = e.Company;
```

Result: variable `c` contains `null`

(B)

```
var e = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
var c1 = e.Company;
e.CompanyId = 2;
var c2 = e.Company;
```

Result: variable `c2` is the same as `c1` and references the `Company` with `Id=1`

Unfortunately all I can suggest you is a workaround and not a general solution. The workaround is to include calls like this after changing the FK property:

```
e.CompanyId = 2;
db.Entry(e).Reference(x => x.Company).IsLoaded = false; // The "fix"
var c = e.Company; // Works
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying the behavior and giving me a workaround.  I appreciate it!